# Compatibility with Intel Xeon E3-1500M processors

Tags: lenovo

new here, just wondering if it looks positive for Ubuntu compatibility with the yet-to-be-released Intel Xeon E3-1500M series processors (e.g., Lenovo P50/70 laptops)?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it. Specs for P50 or P70 say they'll come with Windows 10 or 7, RHEL, or Ubuntu. https://djpdld25uved3.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/WW_DS_Q2-16_ThinkPad_P50_Final.pdf